# Change cursor when mouse hover page background

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change cursor when mouse is over page body background (background is an advertisement)

I tried this:

```
<script>
    var $bodyb = $('body');
    $($bodyb).hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','auto');
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working. Any solutions?

Comment: FYI `$body` is a jQuery object, so you don't need to wrap it again; `$bodyb.hover(...`

Comment: Just a point but whenever the mouse is within the browser it will trigger the hover so why not just set your cursor to pointer in your style sheet?

Comment: The mouse will always be over the body tag no matter where it is on the page because all of your other elements are wrapped in the body tag

Comment: Yes, I think the same, thats my answer, if you gonna do it on the body, forget about hover, just add cursor: pointer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
body {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: If its on body, its always gonna be hover, isnt ?

Or 

body:hover { cursor: pointer }

Comment: body:hover {} indeed.

Comment: Yes, of course, explain differences between what I wrote please

Comment: Just use your eyes : `body { cursor:pointer;} != body:hover{cursor:pointer;}`

Comment: Use your eyes please, I wrote above exactly the same, and my point is, you ALWAYS hover the body !

Answer (score 2):

Dont wrap $bodyb into another $(); Just do

```
  $bodyb.hover...
```

Answer (score 1):

Place **Hover** event inside  **Ready** event. 
Also, change selector `$($bodyb)` to `$bodyb`.

```
 var $bodyb = $('body');
 $(document).ready( function () {
      $bodyb.hover(function() {
            $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
        }, function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','auto');
       });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working, but I don't have pointer hover background

```
(function(){

            document.body.onclick = function(e){
            var t = null;
            if (!e){ var e = window.event; }
            if (e.target){ t = e.target; }
            else if (e.srcElement){ t = e.srcElement; }
            if (t.nodeType == 3){ t = t.parentNode; }
            if (t.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'body' || t.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'html' || (t.id && t.id == 'pub5header')){
                window.open('http://www.external-url.com/');
            }
            };
    f();
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I made a simpler thing, instead of searching body to change cursor, just made the opposite... If cursor is out of my container... Change cursor to pointer:

```
$( "#container" ).hover(
   function() {
   $(document.body).css({ 'cursor': 'auto' })
   }, function() {
   $(document.body).css({ 'cursor': 'pointer' })
   }
);
```

Comment: Facepalm ... really, why would you want to change the cursor on the whole body ? And if you really want, just use css...

Comment: it was for adding clickable backgoun advertisement I've got a background image, I want user to be able to click on background image to be redirected to ad page